# VueJS: Using v-html to appendChild not working, why?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

In this simple [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-v-html-to-append-child-elements-02077), HTML elements are stored in an data array, `v-html` bound to a div to render those element as child to that div . But it's not working, When adding new Element, the element is not rendered, instead `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` is what shown.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <child />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from "./components/child";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    child
  }
};
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="addNewEl">Add New Element</button>
    <div v-for="el in elList" v-html="el"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  data() {
    return {
      elList: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNewEl() {
      var para = document.createElement("P"); // Create a <p> node
      var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph."); // Create a text node
      para.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <p>
      this.elList.push(para);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.addNewEl();
  }
};
</script>
```

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong and show the proper Vue way to append child to a parent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since `v-html` expects a string to be parsed as HTML, you cannot use this directive when rendering HTML elements programmatically.

Use the `outerHTML` property of the element instead. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="addNewEl">Add New Element</button>
    <div v-for="el in elList" v-html="el.outerHTML"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. adding `el` via `el.outerHTML` actually removes all eventListener attached to that element (when removing from an existing element and adding/pushing to `elList` array. Is there any way to preserve the eventListeners while doing it the vue way. Thanks

Comment: @appu Can you show your code on how you're adding the event listeners?

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-html--loses-event-binding-f66or) of actual issue using `v-html=el.outerHTML`. In demo, images are manuallyAdded by `Vue2Dropzone` in childZones. `fileWasAdded`(event) fires when img are added to dropzone. Here I create a new elem, append dropzones `file.previewTemplate` to it & adds elem to a data array, causing `previewElements` computed to evaluate(this way loses original click event). Another way is appendsChild 'file.previewTemplate' directly to DOM `$refs.childZoneRef (preserve click binding, but this isnt vue way). See `slide-template.vue`

Comment: Did you have a chance to read my last comment or look at this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/v-html--loses-event-binding-f66or). Pls help if you can. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the method using:

```js
addNewEl() {
  this.elList.push("<p>This is a paragraph.</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding elements directly to the DOM is not necessary and really bad way to do things in Vue. This is how to do it in "Vue way":

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="addNewPara">Add New Para</button>
    <div>
     <p v-for="(p, index) in para" :key="index">{{ p }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  data() {
    return {
      para: ['This is a paragraph 1', 'This is a paragraph 2'],      
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNewPara() {
      this.para.push(`This is a paragraph ${this.para.length + 1}`)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```